# Is there a way to install Homebrew via graphical interface?

Tags: macos, user-interface, command-line-interface, homebrew

For whatever reason, my place of work distrust installations via CLI.
Is there a GUI installation that can be installed that would keep the IT department happy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s [Cakebrew](https://www.cakebrew.com/), a GUI wrapper around Homebrew; but it doesn’t install Homebrew for you for now:

> It is important to note that Cakebrew doesn't install Homebrew for you. To install Homebrew, please visit their website.
>
> Installing Homebrew though Cakebrew is currently in the To-Do List =)

There’s no way to install Homebrew via GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I'll just have to find some work around.

Thanks again!